# Can't set iOS Autolayout multiplier to zero

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout

**What I'm trying to do:** 
I'm trying to use autolayout constraints to be able to dynamically show/hide views, but I want the views to effectively take up 0 space when hidden (so the normal hidden property isn't useful to me).

**Approach:**
I'm programmatically doing all of my layout using NSLayoutConstraints (note, using Xamarin C#, not Objective c), so I am trying to programmatically switch between a set of "visible" constraints (normal layout, this was always working fine) and "hide" constraints, which sets the width and height to zero.

I am doing some basic tests where I can remove a width constraint and then set a  new one to do whatever I want. But, whenever I try to define (let alone add to the view) a constraint with a multiplier and constant of zero, the multiplier in the NSLayoutConstraint magically changes to 1. For example, my hide-width constraint is defined as:

```
NSLayoutConstraint c1 = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(view, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 0f, 0f);
```

I inspect the constraint `c1`, the multiplier is 1 and the constant is 0. `view` is the view to which I am adding the constraint (a `UIButton` in this case).

**Question:** Is it possible to set an autolayout constraint multiplier to 0 like this? If so, is there something special about a `UIButton` that prevents me from doing this? Ideally, I would like to be able to do this show/hide for pretty much any `UIView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 0 multiplier was broken/"considered silly" in iOS8.

The solution is to set the constant to 0 and leave the multiplier at 1.

Comment: Ah, so with a second item (view) that is `null` and second attribute `NoAttribute`, a multiplier of 1 and constant 0 effectively computes the width to 0? That seems strange to me, especially if it effectively does equate to 0, why not just let me put 0! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: In iOS 7 there were things that were allowed that were disallowed in 8.  Multipliers of 0, aligning left edges to leading edges, two name two.

Comment: Blooming annoying along with preventing multiplier animation/adjustment

Comment: "The 0 multiplier was broken/"considered silly" in iOS8." Can you point me to any documentation regarding this change?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this was never documented, it just went from being valid to being _not valid_.

Answer (score 5):

CGFLOAT_MIN works fine for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10360443)

Comment: CGFLOAT_MIN is very close to zero. Yes, you can not set it to zero.

Comment: Please edit your post and put the information from your comment directly into your post. Maybe you can also explain how to use what you suggest. IMHO that would turn your comment-like post into a true answer. We at SO strive for maintaining high-quality Q&As. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: `CGFLOAT_MIN` has been renamed to `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`

Answer (score 1):

set the multiplier to `0.000001` works for me.